# How can I change placeholder in angular strap select

Tags: select, placeholder

I use angular strap for select and it works very well. Cool!
So my question is simple : is there a simple method to change placeholder after display of the button/combo. I use $translate in my application and it seems that placeholder attribute is compiled and thus not change with scope change.
Regards.